# C# exclude duplicate code from two method returning expression

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have two functions, returning expression translated to EF.:

```
 public static Expression<Func<TripLanguage, TripViewModel>> ToSearchModel(ILookup<int, TagViewModel> tags)
    {            
        return tripLanguage => new TripViewModel()
        {
            From = tripLanguage.From,
            To = tripLanguage.To,
            Annotation = tripLanguage.Description.Truncate(Strings.TRUNCATE_ANOTATION),
            Level = tripLanguage.Trip.Level,
            BicycleType = tripLanguage.Trip.BicycleType,
            UrlId = tripLanguage.UrlId,
            Distance = tripLanguage.Trip.Distance,
            Tags = tags[tripLanguage.TripId], //This is only different and in function args of course
            MainImage = tripLanguage.Trip.Images.OrderBy(s => s.Date).Select(i => new ImageViewModel
            {
                Filename = i.Filename,
                Id = i.Id,
                Title = i.Title
            }).Take(1)
        };
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TripLanguage, TripViewModel>> ToSearchModel()
    {
        return tripLanguage => new TripViewModel()
        {
            From = tripLanguage.From,
            To = tripLanguage.To,
            Annotation = tripLanguage.Description.Truncate(Strings.TRUNCATE_ANOTATION),
            Level = tripLanguage.Trip.Level,
            BicycleType = tripLanguage.Trip.BicycleType,
            UrlId = tripLanguage.UrlId,
            Distance = tripLanguage.Trip.Distance,                
            MainImage = tripLanguage.Trip.Images.OrderBy(s => s.Date).Select(i => new ImageViewModel
            {
                Filename = i.Filename,
                Id = i.Id,
                Title = i.Title
            }).Take(1)
        };
    }
```

The only different is `Tags` collection. Is possible something like call method, without arguments and add Tags attribute which exclude duplicate code? Or Use some inheritance expression?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Call the second method and just populate the Tags property on returned object. No need to use the property setter solely in object initializer list.

Comment: And you are sure your first query (with tags) is converted correctly to SQL query and not executed in memory?

Comment: @Evk Yes, it is true. This create IQueryable object and after call for example ToList() is executed query of course. ToSearchModel is called in Select function. But I still need remove duplicate code, if it is possible.

Comment: No I understand how this works in general, I'm just not sure how it can convert `Tags = tags[tripLanguage.TripId]` to SQL.

Comment: @Evk so, it will return only collection, through object indexer. After this it is converted to sql, like simple collection of IDs. It works well.

Comment: When EF Core cannot translate part of your LINQ to sql - it will just execute that part on client (unless you explicitly disable that, if you do - it will throw exception instead). So most likely your select will be executed on client anyway because of those Tags. You might think it works well but I'd better double-check that it really executes this part as SQL query. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: @Evk Ok, I will check SQL tomorrow I'm not at the correct pc now. Thank you. But it is to current problem, which I need to resolve. Is possible to call expression without args and add any properties to expression?

Comment: It is complicated. My point here is: your Tags most likely causes this to evaluate at client side. If that is true - most likely you are not fine with that. Then you will have to set tags later - after your query is executed and materialized (so after `ToList()` call), and your problem will no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first method to work with `null` tags, and provide a `null` default for it:

```
public static Expression<Func<TripLanguage,TripViewModel>> ToSearchModel(ILookup<int, TagViewModel> tags = null) {
    return tripLanguage => new TripViewModel() {
        From = tripLanguage.From,
        To = tripLanguage.To,
        Annotation = tripLanguage.Description.Truncate(Strings.TRUNCATE_ANOTATION),
        Level = tripLanguage.Trip.Level,
        BicycleType = tripLanguage.Trip.BicycleType,
        UrlId = tripLanguage.UrlId,
        Distance = tripLanguage.Trip.Distance,
        Tags = tags?[tripLanguage.TripId], // <<== Note the question mark
        MainImage = tripLanguage.Trip.Images.OrderBy(s => s.Date).Select(i => new ImageViewModel
        {
            Filename = i.Filename,
            Id = i.Id,
            Title = i.Title
        }).Take(1)
    };
}
```